# How can I change flatpickr default timezone

Tags: flatpickr

I am using flatpickr in order to set a date,

```
onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    var myDate = selectedDates[0];
```

First I am tracing selecteDate[0] and gives me a string

```
Thu Dec 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (GMT-05:00)
```

Then I am tracing myDate and seems that is been converted to GMT+0000 ISO string.

```
2018-12-20T05:00:00.000Z
```

So my question is where does the flatpickr picks the GMT-0500 from?
Is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be possible to do that (currently).
https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/1532

Apparently, flatpickr uses, by default, the timezone of the computer.